# What does iconv stand for?

Tags: iconv

I was trying to figure out why it's called `iconv`... and I was thinking it means something like:

`i` `CONVersion`

I can't figure out what the `i` stands for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More googling answered my own question...

> This uses system facilities to convert a character vector between encodings: the ‘i’ stands for ‘internationalization’.

http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/iconv.html

Comment: Note that that's from the R package documentation. I doubt `iconv(1)` and `iconv(3)` originated in R.

Comment: @muru When I saw "R" I immediately thought of its use in the context of Android application development :)